# QThreadPool : Qt::QueuedConnection fails

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, threadpool, qthread

I have a C++ Qt program that uses `QThreadPool` to process files in no more than `MAX_THREAD_COUNT` threads. And I'm having troubles with `Qt::QueuedConnection`. It looks like signals got lost. But with `Qt::DirectConnection` it works pretty perfect.

I'd be thankful if someone will explain what's going on.

**UPDATE**: This code works well in Qt, but not in Visual Studio 2005. In VS it stops after the first thread finished (but works with `Qt::DirectConnection`)

That's how it looks:

Manager.h:

```
#ifndef MANAGER_H
#define MANAGER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThreadPool>
#include <QDebug>
#include "threadbody.h"

class Manager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT   
private:
    QList<QString> processedfiles;
    QList<QString> resultfiles;
    bool ok;
    QString lasterror;
public slots:
    void addToProcessedFiles(const QString& filename);
    void addToResultFiles(const QString& filename);
    void setErrorMessage(const QString& message);
    void startNewThread();
public:
    bool startManager(const QString& firstfile);
    explicit Manager(QObject *parent = 0);
   ~Manager();

};

#endif // MANAGER_H
```

ThreadBody.h:

```
#ifndef THREADBODY_H
#define THREADBODY_H

#include <QTemporaryFile>
#include <QRunnable>
#include <QTextStream>
#define MAX_THREAD_COUNT 4

class ThreadBody : public QObject, public QRunnable
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QString filename;
public:
     ThreadBody(const QString& filename);
     ~ThreadBody();
     void run();
signals:
    void sendResult(const QString& filename);
    void sendFileName(const QString& filename);
    void taskDone();
    void threadError(const QString& message);
};

#endif // THREADBODY_H
```

Manager.cpp:

```
Manager::Manager(QObject *parent) :
   QObject(parent)
{
    ok=true;
    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(MAX_THREAD_COUNT);
}
void Manager::addToProcessedFiles(const QString& filename)
{
    processedfiles.push_back(filename);
    if(QThreadPool::globalInstance()->activeThreadCount()<MAX_THREAD_COUNT)
           startNewThread();
}
void Manager::addToResultFiles(const QString& filename)
{
    resultfiles.push_back(filename);
}
void Manager::setErrorMessage(const QString& message)
{
    ok=false;
    lasterror=message;
}
void Manager::startNewThread()
{
    if(processedfiles.isEmpty())
        return;
    if(!ok)
        return;
    QString filename=processedfiles.takeFirst();
    ThreadBody* task=new ThreadBody(filename);
    connect(task,SIGNAL(taskDone()),this,SLOT(startNewThread()),Qt::QueuedConnection);
    connect(task,SIGNAL(sendResult(const QString&)),this,SLOT(addToResultFiles(const QString&)),Qt::QueuedConnection);
     connect(task,SIGNAL(sendFileName(const QString&)),this,SLOT(addToProcessedFiles(const QString&)),Qt::QueuedConnection);
     connect(task,SIGNAL(threadError(const QString&)),this,SLOT(setErrorMessage(const QString&)),Qt::QueuedConnection);
     qDebug()<<"thread starts";
     QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(task);
 }

 bool Manager::startManager(const QString& firstfile)
 {
     processedfiles.push_back(firstfile);
     startNewThread();
     QThreadPool::globalInstance()->waitForDone();
     return ok;
 }

 Manager::~Manager(){}
```

ThreadBody.cpp:

```
#include "threadbody.h"
#include <QThreadPool>

ThreadBody::ThreadBody(const QString& filename)
{
   this->filename=filename;
}

ThreadBody::~ThreadBody(){}
void ThreadBody::run()
{
    QFile file(filename);
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QString message=QString("Thread can't open file=%1: %2").arg(filename).arg(file.errorString());
        emit threadError(message);
        emit taskDone();
        return;
    }
    QTextStream in(&file);
    QTemporaryFile newProcessedFile;
    newProcessedFile.setAutoRemove(false);
    if(!newProcessedFile.open())
    {
        QString message="Thread can't open temporary file";
        emit threadError(message);
        emit taskDone();
        return;
    }
    QTextStream out(&newProcessedFile);
    QTemporaryFile resultFile;
    resultFile.setAutoRemove(false);
    if(!resultFile.open())
    {
        QString message="Thread can't open temporary file";
        emit threadError(message);
        emit taskDone();
        return;
    }
    QTextStream resultOut(&resultFile);
    while(!in.atEnd())
    {
        //!---time consuming task---!//
        //example//
        QString currentLine=in.readLine();
        out<<currentLine;
        resultOut<<currentLine;
    }
    resultFile.close();
    newProcessedFile.close();
    file.remove();
    emit sendResult(resultFile.fileName());
    emit sendFileName(newProcessedFile.fileName());
    emit taskDone();
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "manager.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   Manager manager;
   QString filename="C:/airtest/ask.cpp";
   manager.startManager(filename);
   return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: `Manager` doesn't inherit `QObject`, nor does it use the `Q_OBJECT` macro. You're sure that this is your code?

Comment: BTW, this wouldn't be even compiled, because `connect` take `QObject*` as third parameter, but you give `Manager*` (aka `this`) to it

Comment: oh, my fault. Forgot to write it in this code example.

Comment: What do you see in `output` window in your IDE while running under Debug ? *Qt writes there all errors that occurs in runtime*

Comment: Provide code that actually builds and reproduces the issue, state more clearly what isn't working

Comment: There is no error at all. It ends after the first thread finished. But with Qt::DirectConnection it calls startNewThread() and a new thread runs.

Comment: Nothing calls startManager which calls startNewThread in your example

Comment: I fixed code. Now it works in Qt.

Comment: try removing `QThreadPool::globalInstance()->waitForDone();`

Comment: without `QThreadPool::globalInstance()->waitForDone();` It ends after first call.